# How do I get consistent data across different timezones if I am saving all the dates in UTC +0

Tags: javascript, python, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a system where users from Washington DC can create a `post`. This post is saved in my system in UTC +0 time. Then, I can use a reporting system which will give me info about every created post in a certain date range. Lets say I select a date range from `March 21st 00:00:00` to `March 28th 23:59:59` but in my system someone created a post on `March 28th 22:30:00` Washington DC time. Washington DC is several hours behind UTC, so this post would be saved at around `March 29th 02:30:00`, and so when I generate the report for March 21st to March 28th, I will not get the correct result because there is 1 post that has been created on March 28th Washington time, but that is March 29th UTC +0 time.

I first solved this by obtaining the UTC offset of the client and sending it to the server, and so adding that offset to my date range:

```
// JavaScript
"offsetHours" : parseInt(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / -60)
"offsetMinutes" : (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / -60) % 1 * 60
// Python
_range["from"] = strToDate(_range["from"]) - datetime.timedelta(hours = int(request.headers["offsetHours"]), minutes=int(request.headers["offsetMinutes"]))
```

This solved the issue, but it raised another. Now if I generate a report for the same time range (from 21st to 28th March) from 2 different timezones, I will get different results. This is due to the fact that the 2 users have different offsets and so they affect the `from` range in different intervals.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I will get different results" ? How is your reporting tool affected by the user using the reporting tool's timezone? From what you have described, it sounds like you are converting from UTC timezone to the Locale timezone, purely based on what is saved in the `post`

Comment: You have a secondary problem: `new Date()` gets the *current* date/time, and thus `new Date().getTimezoneoffset()` returns the *current* offset.  It is not necessarily the same for all dates and times.  Please read the section titled "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: @Matt good catch, I fixed it by providing the date object with the beginning of the date range, so now I get the time offset relevant to the selected date range, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not necessarily describing a *problem*, but rather a side effect of how local times around the world work.

At any given time, there is *usually* more than one "date" in effect somewhere in the world. If you are saving the timestamp of an event that took place, and you have customers around the world, you're not necessarily saving it with the same date that the user thought it was in their own time zone.  This is true whether you align the timestamps to UTC or to a specific time zone.

Therefore, you must make a business decision about how your application is intended to work.  Do you want your daily reports to reflect posts that were made within a UTC day, or within the day according to the time zone of your business's headquarters?  Then store the timestamp in UTC and (optionally) adjust to your business's time zone before or during reporting.

If however you want the daily reports to reflect the date in the user's time zone, then you might want to also store the user's time zone ID (such as `America/New_York` - not a numeric offset) so that you could convert to that.  Keep in mind that if user's are in different time zones, your reports might look strange when examined from a single time zone's perspective.

Another technique that is often used (primarily for performance reasons, but also for clarity of logic), is to keep both a UTC-based timestamp *and* a separate field for the "business date" that applies.  Usually such a field is *just* a date field, storing a value such as `2021-03-29` without any time or time zone.   This field can be pre-converted to a time zone according to whatever rules you decide are applicable for your business.  It then becomes a great candidate for an index and works well for range queries for daily reports.

In the end - there is no one "right" way to do it.  You have to decide what works best for your use case.  If you are working for a larger company and unsure of the business requirements, then ask someone who might already perform a similar activity manually.  (Often this is an accounting or sales person in a larger organization.)

Comment: To be clear - with the timestamp of an event that already took place (such as a post, an order, etc.) always store the timestamp either in terms of UTC or using a local time with offset, in a data type such as a `datetimeoffset` that can easily be indexed and viewed with respect to UTC.  The second field approach is *optional*.  You should never *only* store a past timestamp in terms of a user's local time without an offset.

Comment: The main issue or concern is that the company that uses the platform has an offshore office just for recording. There are different officess all across Europe, Australia and New Zealand, and I need to somehow make it so when you generate a report for a specific range (21sto to 28th March for example) from any of these location, you will get the same data

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself is, if a transaction takes occurs and office A sees it as happening on `2021-01-01` from their perspective, but office B sees that same transaction as happening on `2020-12-31` from their perspective, which date do you use in a report shared by both offices?  There's not a wrong or right answer. It's something you have to decide. You *might* choose "always A" or "always B" or "whichever the user is closer to" or "whichever the goods ship from" or "whichever the customer first registered with" or some other approach.